# How can I stop nautilus from scrolling the window when I move a file out of a directory?

Tags: nautilus

Say I have a folder that has a lot of directories, and a lot of files in it.  I click the arrow to expand the folder and then drag the folder down to the file list in the parent directory.  When I release it, nautilus moves the window so that the file you moved is still in the visible plane.  This causes me to lose track of what directory I was in.

Is there some way to disable this, or to hold down a key while I'm moving the file so the file isn't followed?  It seems like an ideal behavior to be able to control.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, it is not possible. But as a workaround you can press `F3` and use Nautilus in dual pane mode. If you drag files from the left pane to the right, you should not lose track.